# Github action failing while running the job for deploying the source code into App engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, github-actions

I'm using GCP Cloud Provider and Webpack Bundler to bundle the source code. While deploying the source code into the app engine in Github action, it was failing with the error that the **entry path was not valid**, but in the local build, it was processed successfully.

The action version I'm using in the GitHub workflow was

```
uses:google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76202114/edit) your question and add your workflow. The above line is not valid config. It's hard to say anything without more details.